# When I press uibarbutton item guard let statement does not work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

```
for colored in coloredTexts {
    guard let index = self.find(value: "\(colored)", in: self.myResultArr) else {
        
        return
    }
    print(index)
}
```

Above code runs when I press my `UIBarButtonItem`.

```
func find(value searchValue: String, in array: [String]) -> Int?{

    for (index, value) in array.enumerated()
    {
        if value == searchValue {
            return index
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

I wrote my code like this, but I cannot see anything in my log window if I don't use the `guard let` statement. I got optional values, but I need actually indexes.

Actually I'm searching in `myResultArr`. I wrote this like but I got an "index out of range" error

```
for colored in coloredTexts{
    let index = myResultArr.firstIndex(of: "(colored)")
    print(index!)
}
```

Comment: You know, that it can be simplified as `firstIndex(where:)` or `firstIndex(of:)`?. Could you print `coloredTexts` and `myResultArr`? Should you get the same result at all?

Comment: Actually I m searching in myResultArr I wrote this like but I got index out of range error                                                                                                                                for colored in coloredTexts{
            
            let index = myResultArr.firstIndex(of: "\(colored)")
            print(index!)
        }

Comment: okey I wrote if index != nil print bla bra thank your bro